# Object clips in camera view

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

In my camera view my objects are clipped. I know the "default answer": clipping end value but I changed this already to 100000000 for the camera. The normal 3d view does not clip when I use 1000 end clip value but the camera view does and the render also.

Where can I also change a value? What Is my mistake?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your [blend file?](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: ok.
www.mevendia.de/fehler1/fehlerreport.blend

Comment: Just set clipping End to 500

Comment: in my project that does not make any difference

Comment: @AlexanderHaase tested: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ewREx.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just probably switched wrong clipping value.
Select the camera and in camera panel increase the clipping: (marked in green)

[image]

Comment: You saved me!! :,) Thanks!